# pandas dataset transformation to normalize the data

Tags: python, json, pandas, denormalized

I have a csv file like this:
[image: Input DataFrame]

I want to transform it into a pandas dataframe like this:
[image: Output DataFrame]

Basically i'm trying to normalize the dataset to populate a sql table.

I have used json_normalize to create a separate dataset from genres column but I'm at a loss over how to transform both the columns as shown in the above depiction.

Some suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Avoid adding example data as a picture, it's not possible to copy and paste it in an editor to use it ourselves. Add your example data as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `genre_id` is the only numeric value (*as shown in the picture*), you can use the following:

```
#find all occurrences of digits in the column and convert the list items to comma separated string.
df['genre_id'] = df['genres'].str.findall(r'(\d+)').apply(', '.join)

#use pandas.DataFrame.explode to generate new genre_ids by comma separating them.
df = df.assign(genre_id = df.genre_id.str.split(',')).explode('genre_id') 

#finally remove the extra space
df['genre_id']  = df['genre_id'].str.lstrip() 

#if required create a new dataframe with these 2 columns only
df = df[['id','genre_id']]
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked after I updated my pandas version since explode() attribute for dataframe is only available in pandas 0.25 and above.